# How can I merge and convert cells in vb.NET datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cells

I will start by explaining what I am trying to achieve.

I have a DataGridView in Visual Studio and when I click on a cell, that cell is converted to a button. Reason for this is I want the grid to look like a project planner. So I want people to select a number of cells (on the same line) and on MouseUp the cells must get converted to one button.

I managed to convert only 1 cell at a time to a button but when I select many cells it simply doesn't let me do it. (and I am not sure how to achieve this)

As you can see from the image below, when I click on individual cells they get converted to button but ultimately I want to select a number of cells and on MouseUp it should convert them to a button.

http://postimage.org/image/o0kkgsnpp/

Reason I chose a button is because in future I will add drag and drop functionality so that I am able to drag that button to a new line for example. It doesn't mean I can't do this another way if it is more efficient so any recommendation will be welcome.

This is the code I am using to convert to button so please have a look at it and let me know how I can achieve this functionality:

> Blockquote

.
   .
   .
 AddHandler Grid.CellMouseUp, AddressOf Grid_MouseUp

```
End Sub

Private Sub Grid_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)

    Dim ButtonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonCell

    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In Grid.SelectedCells
        Grid(cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex) = ButtonColumn

    Next cell

End Sub
```

> Blockquote

Comment: or would it be easier to use Graphics and draw a rectangle? But then I wont be able to drag/drop/snap to grid that rectangle so I believe a button will be my best option. Any ideas guys?

Comment: There is no straightforward way of doing this. If you can, I would recommend moving to WPF - this sort of thing is much easier. The other option is to buy a custom control with the functionality. If you are stuck with basic winforms, every approach I've seen has involved custom painting of some description. Here is one example http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/152113/How-can-i-merge-DataGridView-Rows-Cells-with-Equal

Comment: thanks for the reply @DavidHall. How different is WPF and will I need to make major changes to my project in order to use WPF? AS you can probably tell from this comment, I have never used WPF but you are not the only one who has suggested I use it for this project. I guess I have to ask uncle Google what he thinks of WPF and hopefully if I ask nicely enough I might be able to get something out of him. Thanks for your help one more time

Comment: It really depends - WPF still uses C# but the approach to designing the UI is very different, with XAML - there is not straightforward way of converting winforms to WPF. I'd recommend checking some tutorials to see if making the change is feasible, though it might turn out that sticking to winforms and either rethinking the ui or doing the custom painting is your best bet.

Comment: @DavidHall thank you for your reply. I think I will spend the rest of the night trying to get my head around WPF. I would personally prefer to code all night in winforms but as people say 20% of initial research produces 80% of the results and I see it as a challenge so why not :P. Thank you for your time and advice

Comment: Found a good tutorial here if anybody in a similar situation is interested: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22980/WPF-A-Beginner-s-Guide-Part-1-of-n

Comment: @DavidHall would it be possible to draw a rectangle and then implement the drag and drop functionality so rectangles can be dragged? i am sorry to resuscitate the post but I had a look at WPF and it doesn't really suit me and this project unfortunately. I have been trying to find a solution to this and got nowhere I am pretty desperate